# What part of Britain is Mossy Bottom Farms from Shaun the Sheep located in?

Tags: plot-explanation, shaun-the-sheep

We know Wallace and Gromit live in Wigan.

It isn't clear to me where Shaun the Sheep lives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's not stated.

No specific location is ever stated (so far) but it's generally assumed to be "northern England"

> Shaun, an unusually bright and clever sheep, lives with his flock at Mossy Bottom Farm (the name being revealed in the fourth season), a traditional small northern English farm.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaun_the_Sheep)

Comment: You could actually place it reasonably accurately by the style of the building and the [dry stone walls](https://www.conservationhandbooks.com/dry-stone-walling/walls-in-the-landscape/characteristic-regional-walls/)